# Wrap selected text with Select2

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

How can I get the selected text in [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) to wrap instead of using an ellipsis?  The option items wrap, but I'd like the input field to be able to expand down instead of over.

**Here's an example**:

```js
$('.select2').select2();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="select2" style="width:100px">
  <option value="AL">Really long name that normally wouldn't be visible</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

By default [Select2 adds the following code](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/src/scss/_single.scss):

```css
.select2-selection--single {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

However, removing these properties doesn't do the trick because they are still nested in other containers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think it is the `.select2-selection__rendered` element that needs some tweaking.
How about something like this ?

```
.select2-selection--single {
  height: 100% !important;
}
.select2-selection__rendered{
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  text-overflow: inherit !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

---

```js
$('.select2').select2();
```

```css
.select2-selection--single {
  height: 100% !important;
}
.select2-selection__rendered{
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  text-overflow: inherit !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="select2" style="width:100px">
  <option value="AL">Really long name that normally wouldn't be visible</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

#### Update

`!important` is not required. Thanks to @KyleMit for pointing it out.

Comment: Just a note that you don't need `!important` here.  You just need to have a higher degree of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the current selector.  Also, unless you want to apply to every select2 object, it's probably better to use a class to apply the styles selectively.  Here's a [fiddle with both of those examples](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/jj7apvky/)

Comment: hey, thanks for the note. I had a feeling that it was not required but for some reason it was not working. Just realized that in code snippet stylesheet was loaded first and css next and hence it was not working. Anyways, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  height: 35px !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.