# virtual-scrolling web autocomplete for thousands of variable-height items?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In our web app, we want to add an autocomplete-enabled search box where auto-complete results:

1. can be vertically scrolled, so that users can browse through a long list of matching results, or can even browse through the full list before typing anything. (we want to pop up the autocomplete list as soon as the search box gets focus)
2. can have variable heights of each autocomplete item, because each item will have a name (which in some cases could wrap to two lines) and a short description (which will be 1-3 lines long).
3. can contain formatted HTML (e.g. bold text for names) not just plain text. We're using Knockout.js templates for rendering this formatted HTML but are flexible in case another technology is needed.

The source data for the autocomplete list is sitting in a JavaScript array on the client. Also on the client is the filtering logic that determines which results will be shown as the user types.  So in theory we should have a blazing-fast solution because there are no server dependencies.

The problem is that rendering the entire auto-complete list (e.g. using an implementation like [JQuery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight)) creates many thousands of DOM elements and is very slow to render on the client.  Knockout.js overhead makes it worse.  The browser locks up for a few seconds when the user sets focus to the search box!

We've tried the [Kendo UI virtual-scrollable autocomplete widget](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/virtualization#ui), but Kendo's implementation is limited to fixed-height elements.

Any suggestions for what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [select2](https://select2.github.io/).  While it isn't an autocomplete widget, it does all the things you're asking for in the form of a combo box.  It can be configured to allow the user to type in values that aren't in the list of selections as well.  Finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788171/wrap-selected-text-with-select2) is a trick to alter the CSS to allow word-wrapped items.

I haven't used it with a very large array, but as you say, in theory it should run fast.  Maybe it's worth investigating.